# Prisma deploy - authentication error for local deployment

Tags: docker, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma, prisma-binding

I am trying to run prisma deploy using a local prisma server running on port 4466 but when I run prisma deploy I get this message

```
Authenticating...
Opening https://app.prisma.io/cli-auth?secret=$2a$08$u3VSbu6GSxSV8l86BFs24O in the browser

Could not open the authentication link, maybe this is an environment without a browser. Please open this url in your browser to authenticate: https://app.prisma.io/cli-auth?secret=$2a$08$u3VSbu6GSxSV8l86BFs24O
```

This is prisma server file

```
mongodb:
   image: mongo:4.2
   container_name: mongodb
   volumes:
     - ./mongo-volume:/data/db
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"   

  prisma-server:
   image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34.10
   container_name: prisma-server
   restart: always
   ports:
     - "4466:4466"
   environment:
     PRISMA_CONFIG: |
       port: 4466
       managementApiSecret: password@123
       databases:
         default:
           connector: mongo
           uri: mongodb://mongodb
```

this is my prisma.yml file. I am running prisma deploy within another dockerfile.

```
endpoint: ${env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT}
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
secret: ${env:PRISMA_SECRET}
databaseType: document
generate:
  - generator: javascript-client
    output: ./src/generated/prisma-client
hooks:
 post-deploy:
  - prisma generate
  - npx nexus-prisma-generate --client ./src/generated/prisma-client --output ./src/generated/nexus-prisma
```

this is my .env file

```
PRISMA_SECRET=password@123
PRISMA_ENDPOINT=http://prisma-server:4466/app/dev
API_SECRET=password@123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me to run prisma deploy within a Dockerfile

```
FROM node:9-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

# To handle 'not get uid/gid' error in alpine linux set unsafe-perm true
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add bash \
    && npm config set unsafe-perm true \
    && chmod +x ./docker-scripts/entrypoint.sh \     
    && yarn install \
    && yarn global add prisma

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["./docker-scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# prisma deploy

 cd /prisma 
 prisma deploy

# go into the project...
 cd /app

 npm run start
```

docker-compose file

```
services:
  prisma-client:
    image: image-name-here 
    container_name: prisma-client
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "4000:4000"
    environment:     
     PRISMA_ENDPOINT: http://prisma-server:4466      
    networks:
     - prisma
```

Now once I did docker-compose prisma client container was also created.